# can i combine 2 templates i purchased online?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates

so i used this template that uses HTML and JS:
http://www.templatemonster.com/website-templates/41790.html

and i want to branch off the site by utlizing this template which uses HTML 5 and JS and Jquery:
http://www.templatemonster.com/website-templates/38198.html

you will want to check out the live demo for the 2nd one..

not sure how to explain it clearly, but i'll try.
right now, i have my site using the 1st template as the core and as the index.html (www.ivegotcrayons.com)
what i want to do is branch off the site using the 2nd template...so it'll be like www.ivegotcrayons.com/ideas.html  will be the 2nd template's index.html

get what i'm trying to say?

is this possible? can i create different folders and have each template link to their respective java or CSS folders? or will they interfere with each other?

please let me know if you need more clarification, its tough for me to explain properly..
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the templates don't use any absolute paths, you should be fine. The `index.html` or `index.php` page is for each subdirectory you create in your web folder. If an index page is missing, it will either show a directory listing, or do something else as configured by your server.

So that means you can have `js` and `css` folders in two separate subdirectories, and index pages that reference those locally, and it will not conflict. It will only conflict if the templates assume something about the directory structure.

```
/var/www/html <--- example web server root directory
index.html    <--- template 1's index page
js/
css/
about/        <--- template 2's root directory
   index.html <--- template 2's index page
   js/
   css/
```

Comment: thanks for replying, 
i understand what you're saying, but how would things be organized?
the templates do not use any absolute paths...
so right now i have everything in my room directory:
css (folder)
js (folder) 
cgi-bin (folder)
bat (folder)
images (folder)
index.html
index2.html

so this is for the 1st template....
how would i create/arrange the sub-directories and would i place the html files in the above location or would i put them in another location?

Comment: Each template should have its own 'root' directory, and their respective index.html files. You should not have to change anything. Just move all the files for the template into your root directory (i.e. the main index), and rename the second template folder 'about'.

Comment: thanks for replying...
i'm not sure i understand how i'm supposed to set it up...
think you could elaborate by providing an example?

Comment: Updated answer to describe what I'm talking about.

Comment: awesome, that helps me a lot...lets me try it out and see how it goes

Comment: looks like it's working. thanks a lot for the help...
if you're curious:
http://ivegotcrayons.com/hercules